# Magento 2: Create Order Programmatically without products in stock

Tags: module, sales-order

Below is code to create order Programatically , it is working fine , i want order to be created even when products is out of stock or less quantity

```
  public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
        263135
        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
 
        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }
 
        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
 
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
 
        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
 
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
 
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
 
        // Create Order From Quote
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
        
        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if($order->getEntityId()){
            $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
        }else{
            $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'd need to allow backorder while creating order, then turn it off after then

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an order without the in-stock Item then you can update the Catalog/Inventory configuration to process the order.

Go to **Store** > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > **Inventory** Tab.

Open the **Product Stock Option** fieldset group and update the below dropdown option.

**Backorders** to **Allow Qty below 0**

[image: config-img]

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. To set the custom order date

After the

`$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);`

You can do

`$order->setCreatedAt(...);`

to set the order date. And then `$this->orderRepository->save($order);` to save that new date

`$this->orderRepository` is an object of `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`

#### 2. Custom shipping amount

For the custom shipping amount, it's a little more complicated. Since you can't just do `$order->setShippingAmount` and get away with it. You must also do `$order->setBaseShippingAmount`, `$order->setGrandTotal`, `$order->setBaseGrandTotal`, etc.

A better way would be to write the logic for custom shipping amount in the shipping method itself. You could also write a plugin specific to your scope (frontend, adminhtml, graphql, api_rest, etc.) to apply that custom shipping amount only for that scope.

And then instead of setting `freeshipping_freeshipping` as the shipping method, set your custom shipping method.

Have a look at [THIS](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html) to know more about how to create a custom shipping method.

Comment: can i skip stock check - get error Product that you are trying to add is not available.

Answer (score 0):

$quote->setIsSuperMode(true) before saving it

Comment: this is not working